# Clear state.route remove page transition with react-navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

For performance reasons, i want clear my `state.routes` and keep only `currentRoute` and `prevRoutes`. I put the index alway on 1.

But my problem is that slide animation is removed :(

My code :

```
const navReducer = (state, action) => {
  const nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);

  switch (action.type) {
    case 'Navigation/NAVIGATE':
      const newState = nextState || state;
      const routes = newState.routes;
      const routesCount = routes.length;

      if (routesCount > 2) {
        const newRoutes = routes.slice(-2);
        return { ...newState, ...{ routes: newRoutes, index: 1 } };
      }
      break;
    case 'Navigation/BACK':
      console.log('Push back');
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }

  return nextState || state;
};
```

Anyone know if i can clear my `state.routes` but with save the default navigation animation ?

Thank you !